# Why Hazelcast can't shutdown on my application server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, hazelcast

I need to deploy my enterprise application on a Websphere Application Server (8.5).

In order to handle hazelcast's lifecycle I prepared the following monitor object:

```
public class HazelMonitor{
    private static HazelcastInstance inst = null;

    public static synchronized getInstance(){
     if(inst == null){
         inst = Hazelcast.getOrCreateInstance(...);
     }
      return inst;
    }

 public static synchronized shutdown(){
       if(inst != null){
           inst.shutdown();
           inst = null;
       }
 }
}
```

Now, my Ejb is like this:

```
public class MyEjb{
 @PostConstruct
 pulic void init(){
   HazelMonitor.getInstance();
 }

 @PreDestroy
 public void close(){
    HazelMonitor.shutdown();
 }
}
```

Everything seems working except when I try to shutdown my server: Hazelcast just doesn't seem to be able to shutdown and, in the end, the server just hangs down forcing me to kill the process.
Once I kill the process I receive an hazelcast exception about a not found class **Node$2**.

What am I doing wrong? How to make sure that Hazelcast gracefully shuts down along with my application?

Comment: have you confirmed that the EJB `@PreDestroy` is actually being invoked and the `.shutdown()` call is happening?

Comment: I guess the classloader is already killed when the `PreDestroy` method is called. Try to wrap it into a try / catch block, log any exception happening.

Answer (score 2):

Which Hazelcast version are you using? We fixed a classloader leakage in 3.8 which could cause such a behavior (see https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/pull/9691).

So please try out Hazelcast 3.8 if you have used an older version before. Otherwise a thread dump would be a great help to see what Hazelcast is doing.

You can find all running Java processes via

```
jps -l
```

and then create the thread dump via

```
jstack <PID>
```